# How to integrate jQuery select2 library into a Symfony3 form?

Tags: jquery-select2, symfony

I am trying to manually integrate the jQuery [`select2`](https://select2.github.io/) library into my Symfony form as a replacement for my select boxes.

Following the manual I have added to the page header:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

In addition I have modified my form class, adding `attr` to each select:

```
->add('kontoWinien', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\konto',
    'attr' => array('class'=>'select2')
))
```

My modified Twig template:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".select2").select2();
    });
</SCRIPT>
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

However **the select2 is still not loaded**.

HTML code generated by symfony3 looks like this:

```
 <head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form name="dziennik" method="post">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".select2").select2();
    });
</script>

<select id="dziennik_kontoWinien" name="dziennik[kontoWinien]" class="select2 form-control">
```

Could you please advise what am i doing wrong?

Comment: you have any console output ? lowercase the script tags

Comment: Have you tried straight up HTML on a non-Symfony generated select box just to see if that works properly?  Are you sure it's not working?  The basic example looks very similar to a normal select box.

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery before the select assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $('select').select2();
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like fcpauldiaz said you'll need to load up jquery before hand. I took your code loaded jquery (and some options so we can see it work) and it worked fine.

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Loading jquery here--><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form name="dziennik" method="post">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".select2").select2();
    });
  </script>

  <select id="dziennik_kontoWinien" name="dziennik[kontoWinien]" class="select2 form-control">
    <option value="test1">test1</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>
  </select>
```